# Uninstalled Ubuntu. Yet it works

Tags: uninstall

I've uninstalled Ubuntu. Yet it works and every time I switch on the computer I get to choose between windows and ubuntu. Is formatting my disk the only option I have?

Answer (score 2):

You want to restore the master boot record, which will mean you lose the `grub` boot manager which is what you are seeing.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Windows 7 disk, go to repair option. Open command prompt.

Run:

```
bootrec/fixmbr
bootrec/fixboot
```

Restart (don't forget to remove Windows 7 disk!!!). Done.

This basically removes [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), the default bootmanager that is installed with Ubuntu to manage dual-boot.
Uninstalling Ubuntu removes the OS, not bootmanager, and if you forcibly remove GRUB, your system won't boot. The above method should work for you.